# Reinstall cake command

Tags: cakephp, composer-php

i have a web application developed using cakephp.
Now I need to make some changes and I need to use the bin / cake command, but the bin folder is not present and not even re-executing the composer command is this created.

How can I regenerate it so that it refers to the version of cake already present?

Thx

Comment: got to https://github.com/cakephp/app/tree/master/bin select your cakephp version and copy that files to your bin

Comment: this is work if i download the correct version. thx

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Open your composer.json and search for your cakephp version by the key "cakephp/cakephp"
2. Create a brand new cakephp project with this version with the command:

   php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:^**3.8** **my_app_name**

where **3.8** should be your cakephp version and **my_app_name** your application name

3. Take the bin folder and copy/paste it to your actual application.